# Mysql trigger after delete with char ID

Tags: mysql, triggers, varchar

i had 3 table like A, B, C the relation is A(ID), B(A.ID, C.ID) B has a foreign key of A, also B has a foreign key of C

i want to make a trigger when B is being deleted, it will delete C aswell. the problem is datatype of C is not integer, so i should put ' ' on the query like this

```
DELETE FROM C WHERE ID = 'AB001';
```

here's my trigger on deleting B

```
BEGIN
DELETE FROM C WHERE ID = Old.CID ;
END
```

how can i put this ' ' on my trigger?

Comment: Why not make c.id an integer? No one / no thing cares about c.id except for the sql internals.

Comment: @Strawberry because the ID of C is customized, not AI from the sql. it has a pattern

Comment: I appreciate that. What I'm saying is that it probably doesn't need to be. The public, human-friendly code need have no bearing on the internal id.

Answer (score 1):

`ID` and `Old.TransactionID` aren't values, they are column names. You don't need to quote either of them.

Having said that, I think a trigger is just the wrong way to go. If you already have a foreign key, just define it as `on delete cascade`, and save yourself the hassle of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: sorry wrong question, i mean i had a table that has a freign key. i want to make when i delete the row from the table that has a foreign key, the table that has a primary key should be deleted, how to do that?

Comment: I agree that a trigger seems like the wrong approach. A cascade will be fine, or even a simple delete